# Optimal search data structure

Tags: java, search, tree, large-files

I searched for this before I post but I couldn't fine something that helps me.
I'm using java. I have a file of 300.000 words (already sorted alphabeticaly). 
I want to load these words in a structure and search if a word that I'll pass
exists or not. I want something that is best for string search. I've seen about
tries (suffix trees) and red-black trees (TreeSet - since I want only keys, and 
no values- in java).

Please if you consider answering provide some explanation about the efficiency 
of your proposition. Thank you.

**EDIT**
The structure will be created by loading the file, and there will be no further 
adding of words. 
Case sensitivity is not required.
I didn't know what stemming is. I know now, but I don't know if it would help.
The file is a dictionary (no translation, just the words of a given language).

Comment: does case-sensitivity matter? and are you using stemming? Do you plan to add more words? Personally I use tries.

Comment: If you have to use JDK classes, I would go for a `Set<String>`. You can back it up by some of its implementations: `HashSet<String>`, `LinkedHashSet<String>` or `TreeSet<String>` depending on your needs when using the `Set<String>`.

Comment: I don't have to, but it would be easier for me. Why don't you post this as an answer? I've edited my question. Please provide your opinion. How would YOU do this? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Hash would be your optimal solution. It searches in constant time as oposed to the treeset wich is log(n) time.

You can also store in constant time, if you declare the set big enough at creation.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

The creation would be in time: n , and you will need to have the sorted set contained in a seperate structure.

This is a solution optimized for searching for duplicates not for memory or adding data.

Comment: I would recommend you link to `HashSet`, as OP does not have key/value pairs.

Comment: With your edit I would say that a HashMap is sufficent. You create the set wit n (300.000) operations and may from there on read with a single (constant time) operation.

Comment: It will be a HashSet as jlordo mentioned. I have only keys, no values.
TreeSet will be O(logn) and HashSet O(n). For this kind of size of data, wouldn't be better if it was logarithmic?

Comment: Hashset has a worst-case lookup of O(n), but it's average-case is O(1).  In addition, a Treeset will need to make repeated calls to `compareTo`, which is O(n) in the size of the string; Hashset will only need to compare hashcodes (constant-time) as well as a single call to `equal` (O(n) in the size of the string)

Comment: Thank you Zim-Zam for the detailed explanation.